# Filter list based on number of digits in strings

Tags: bash

I have long list of entries are recorded in a file, something like this short list:

```
FFF1B976-9DDE-11E7-9C3D-6241D7D553BE
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
6846DFEC-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
6846DFEC-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
--[SNIP]--
```

I want to filter this list based on the number of digits (characters in set `0123456789`) within each entry and if the number of digits more than a specific threshold then keep the string otherwise remove it. in the previous example, how can I keep all the entries that have 18 digits in its names?

Expected output:

```
FFF1B976-9DDE-11E7-9C3D-6241D7D553BE
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
```

Comment: All of those have 32 digits; they just happen to be hexidecimal digits.

Answer (score 7):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '[[:digit:]]' 'NF > 18'
```

We use digits as the field separator, so the number of fields will be one plus the number of digits (`x1y` is split into `x` and `y`), so above we're looking for lines that have *at least* 18 digits.

(with `mawk`, replace `[:digit:]` with `0-9`. `mawk` doesn't support POSIX character classes, but its `[0-9]` contrary to other `awk` implementations matches on 0123456789 only regardless of the locale. Portably, you can use `[0123456789]`, or you can use `[0-9]` if you know the text doesn't contain non-ASCII data).

For lines that have  *exactly* 18 digits, that would be:

```
awk -F '[[:digit:]]' 'NF == 19'
```

With `sed`, for at least 18 digits:

```
sed -e 's/[[:digit:]]/&/18;t' -e d
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -E '(.*[[:digit:]]){18}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that the data are saved in a file called `file.txt`, then you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file.txt | while IFS= read line; do

n=$(echo $line | awk '{print gsub("[0-9]", "")}')
if [[ $n -gt 17 ]]; then 

echo $line
fi
done

FFF1B976-9DDE-11E7-9C3D-6241D7D553BE
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
```

Or

```
awk 'gsub("[0-9]", "&") >= 18'
```

Comment: or, more directly, `awk '{if (gsub("[0-9]", "") > 17) print;}' < file.txt`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, you'd want `awk 'gsub("[0-9]", "&") >= 18'` instead.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller I really don't know, this is what come to mind, very old style ;-)

Comment: Or `awk 'split($0,a,/[0-9]/)>18'`

Answer (score 1):

To find lines with 18 digits (`[0-9]`) and more, you can use `grep`.

```
egrep '([0-9][^0-9]*){18}'
```

or

```
grep -E '([0-9][^0-9]*){18}'
```

### Description

`egrep` is same as `grep -E`.

```
grep      # Command to filter text using regular expressions
-E        # Use extended regex

(
  [0-9]   # Exactly one digit
  [^0-9]* # 0 or more characters except digits
)           
{18}      # Find 18 times
```

Comment: This only finds consecutive digits.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, I was wrong.

Comment: It should be OK now.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the return value of perl's `tr` (similar to using the returnvalue of awk's `gsub`)

```
$ perl -ne 'print if tr{0-9}{0-9} >= 18' file
FFF1B976-9DDE-11E7-9C3D-6241D7D553BE
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
682D9DB6-C0A2-11E8-B7A8-3ECB9C0CC049
```